# WPF and frame rate

Tags: wpf

We know that the default frame rate for WPF is 60 frames per second. And in cases of extensive animations, their frame rates tends to increase the CPU consumption.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henryh/archive/2006/08/23/719568.aspx

But why is the CPU being consumed, shouldnt the GPU actually be used here because WPF takes advantage of graphics card where available isnt? Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect WPF to use the graphics resources when available. However animations can be computationally expensive and I don't wonder if the CPU is being involved.

What value you have for  [RenderCapability.Tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx)?

(Remember that you get the value by `RenderCapability.Tier >> 16`)

The features of the graphics hardware determine the rendering capability of a WPF application.

From [msdn Graphics Rendering Tiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx):

> a rendering tier defines a level of graphics hardware capability and
>   performance for a device that runs a WPF application. The WPF system defines three rendering tiers:
>
> Rendering **Tier 0** No graphics hardware acceleration. All graphics
>   features use software acceleration. The DirectX version level is less
>   than version 9.0.
>
> Rendering **Tier 1** Some graphics features use graphics hardware
>   acceleration. The DirectX version level is greater than or equal to
>   version 9.0.
>
> Rendering **Tier 2** Most graphics features use graphics hardware
>   acceleration. The DirectX version level is greater than or equal to
>   version 9.0.

Comment: I believe if its software rendering, only then CPU will be involved?If the renderingtier is Hardware then probably the GPu will be used?

Comment: I could imagine that the CPU is always involved in animations, in particular when Frame rate is 60 Frames/sec. Of course  in Hardware rendering the CPU will be considerably less used.

Comment: Then can i infer that in machines where there is no GPU, WPF defaults to software rendering and that is very expensive?